# Retrieve data from a webpage

Tags: html, arduino

I have made a webpage which only holds a few divs which have values in them. I want to access these values from arduino. I have connected my arduino to my wifi network using a WiFly shield. I am not sure how I would retrieve the data off of the website I have made.

Website is https://googledrive.com/host/0B5gW3AYRbRMoYU5RaHpNS2ZEY3c/dataRequest.html

The page takes 15 seconds to load the data in so be patient.

the div.id's are coordinate sets, I just want to create a sketch which retrieves the data then posts it to an integer

```
FIND-THE-CONTENT-HERE
String COORDINATES = RETRIEVED-DATA

if (COORDINATES == THESE-COORDINATES) { 
Int value = VALUE-INSIDE-DIV
}
LOOP TO KEEP CHECKING DATA(IF IT HAS BEEN UPDATED)
```

**Current sketch to connect to wifi**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFly.h>

#include "Credentials.h"

char serverName[] = "googledrive.com";

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Serial.println("\n\r\n\rWiFly Shield Terminal Routine");

  WiFly.begin();

  if (!WiFly.join(ssid, passphrase)) {
    Serial.println("Association failed.");
    while (1) {
      // Hang on failure.
    }
  }

  Serial.println("Associated!");
}


void loop() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to get the data from the Arduino.

When a client visits that page they see a list of numbers:

```
129
63
...
70
```

But that URL does not return this list of numbers.  The URL returns some javascript code that runs on the client side and then renders these numbers.  The client CPU, and browser do all the work of querying the database and generating what you see on the screen.

The Arduino will see just the page source code.  Right click on the page and select "view source" and you will see what the Arduino will see.  In order for the Arduino to render the page it would have to have a javascript engine which is far beyond what you can run with a microcontroller.

What you need to do is server side rendering so that all the work is done before the page is sent  In such a case, the server would do all the heavy work and the Arduino would just parse the text.  You don't even have to use HTML -- the page could simply render to plain text which would be well withing the capabilities of a microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

jd5ca is correct, the value are extrapolated by a JS, but he is wrong on the fact that you CAN'T get the data; 
you don0t need a JS engine if you emulate the javascript on the arduino ("port" the JS code to arduino).

Normally the JS do some GET to get JXON/XML formatted data, witch is just a GET on a differnent URI, sometimes WebSocket are involved witch is still possible to implement of arduino. 
But in this case seems like the JS is doing something different, parsing some data from  in witch i can't help you as i lack JQuery knoledge. sorry